# Does java use the registry to locate its default jar files?

Tags: java

**Target Environment**
  Windows 7 (6.1)
  Java 1.8.0_121 64bit

I recently created a minimal java environment consisting of just the single file java.exe in a newly created, empty directory and successfully ran a simple HelloWorld.class file simply by copying it to the same directory and typing:

```
.\java HelloWorld
```

I found this kind of surprising, and wondered if maybe because the version of java I was using (jre 1.8.0_72) had been installed from an .exe file whether there was something in the Windows registry telling java.exe where to find rt.jar and such.
Running the java control panel, you can certainly see java 1.8.0_72 is in there:
[image: java control panel snap-in]
I if I used a java version which was NOT installed (i.e. a standalone java version) would I get a different result?

Comment: Don't post multiple answers to your own question.

Comment: 1. To execute a java application, you need a java runtime environment. Just an executable (java.exe) is usually not enough. 2. It worked in your setup because the PC had it installed somewhere (your screenshot shows it 3 times). With the default installer, an [Environment Variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx) is set to point to the Java installation package. That's how your system locates it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before trying a stand-alone version I think I'll try a computer having NO java on it at all. Same exact set up as before.

Found part of the answer on my wife's Windows 10 computer (which has no java on it):
[image]
Clearly, I should copy java.dll somewhere. Think I'll put it in the same directory as everything else (i.e. the same one as the java.exe), and try that.

Nope. Same as before.

So clearly java is looking in the registry to find its .dll.

I've downloaded jre-8u121-windows-x64.tar.gz. I'm going to try the same experiment with that.

Tried the same experiment with java from the tarball above.  Exact same symptom.  Cannot find java.dll.

Having done a little reading, I see that Embedded Java SE has a way to create custom deployments of java. There appears to be no official analogous mechanism for Java SE for Windows.

Doing a little more reading, I see that there is a mechanism called the Invocation API which can be used to run java, bypassing java.exe. This might be something to try.  Might also be time to start surfing the HOTSPOT code.

More on the Invocation API here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

An intriguing note I also ran into during my reading said this:

*Private vs. public JRE - Installing the JDK installs a private Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) and optionally a public copy. The private JRE is required to run the tools included with the JDK. It has **no registry settings** and is contained entirely in a jre directory (typically at C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0\jre) whose location is known only to the JDK.*

I read this here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-142126.html

You might try this experiment with THAT jre.

Answer (score 0):

Today I also face same problem .and I found the solution for this go-to  your JDK bin copy path from there and peast this path to environment variable path and the priority should be first that mean it should be peast in starting of all path.